# Android emulator: configure how to press Tab to advance to next TextFormField for easier human UI testing?

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator, ios-simulator

(On the web as a keyboard-centric developer I'm spoiled being able to press the Tab key on my keyboard to advance the form focus to the next field.)

I haven't been able to figure out how to do this inside the Android emulator while developing/testing my first Flutter app.  I have to manually move my mouse to bring focus to the next form field.

My gut feeling is that everyone has had this frustration doing their first Flutter form and there must be a simple setting or easy way enable it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is an easy way to move to next field. If you are using `TextFormField` widget, it has `focusNode` property that helps to create a focus node that can be configured using `onFieldSubmitted` callback. If you are making use of the emulator keyboard to switch focus, you can also use `textInputAction` property that you can set to `next`, `done` per your requirement when focus is moving from one field to another. Below is a sample use-case:

I have 2 `TextFormField` widgets in a column with `hintText` `First` and `Second` respectively. When user taps on first field, the emulator keyboard opens and will show `next` button. Taping on it will move cursor focus to second field. Below is working code sample for same:

```
body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'First'
                  ),
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                  focusNode: _firstNode,
                  onFieldSubmitted: (String val) {
                    _firstNode.unfocus();
                    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_secondNode);
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Second'
                  ),
                  focusNode: _secondNode,
                )
              ],
            )
          )
```

`textInputAction: TextInputAction.next` makes the keyboard button show `next` button. Similarly, you can have `textInputAction: TextInputAction.done` for your last field.
`_firstNode` is the focus node we define as `FocusNode _firstNode = FocusNode();` Same for `_secondNode`.

Then in `onFieldSubmitted`, we take away focus from first field and request focus on next field using `FocusScope` by passing `_secondNode` to it. So when user enters input in first field and taps on `next` button on keyboard, the focus will switch to second field.

Also, if you don't want to depend on keyboard next button to switch focus, you can use `onChanged` callback with similar logic as above. Only difference is, this callback is not available for `TextFormField` widget, you will have to use `TextField` widget for it.

Hope this answers your question.